# PHP If statement returning early(amateur)

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm currently struggling with a page that allows a user to complete one of two options. They can either update an existing item in the SQL database or they can delete it. When the customer deletes an option everything runs perfectly well, however whenever a customer updated an item it displays the `Query failed` statement from the delete function before applying the update.

It seems obvious to me that the problem must be in my IF statement and that the `DeleteButton` function isn't exiting if the `$deleteno` variable isn't set. Any help would be appreciated. Excuse the horribly messy code PHP isn't a language I am familiar with. (I have not included the connect information for privacy reasons)

```
function DeleteButton(){
    @mysqli_select_db($con , $sql_db);

    //Checks if connection is successful 
    if(!$con){
        echo"<p>Database connection failure</p>";
    } else {
        if(isset($_POST["deleteID"])) {
            $deleteno = $_POST["deleteID"];
        }
        if(!isset($deleteno)) {
            $sql = "delete from orders where orderID = $deleteno;";
            $result = @mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            if((!$result)) {
                echo "<p>Query failed please enter a valid ID </p>";
            } else {
                echo "<p>Order $deleteno succesfully deleted</p>";
                unset($deleteno);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is the code for the delete button and the following code is for the `UpdateButton` minus the connection information (which works fine).

```
if(isset($_POST["updateID"])) {
    $updateno = $_POST["updateID"];
}
if(isset($_POST["updatestatus"])) {
    if($_POST["updatestatus"] == "Fulfilled") {
        $updatestatus = "Fulfilled";
    } elseif ($_POST["updatestatus"] == "Paid") {
        $updatestatus = "Paid";
    }
}
if(isset($updateno) && isset($updatestatus)) {
    $sql ="update orders set orderstatus='$updatestatus' where orderID=$updateno;";
    $result = @mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(!$result) {
        echo "<p>Query failed please enter a valid ID</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Order: $updateno succesfully updated!</p>";
    }
}
```

Once again these are incomplete functions as I have omitted the connection sections.

Comment: What does the `DeleteButton()` have to do with the update; is the whole code for both inside the same function?

Comment: First thing I can see is a scoping issue. `$con` is not in scope within `DeleteButton()`. Also, suppressing errors (`@` operator) never solved any problem

Comment: @Phil OP states *"When the customer deletes an option everything runs perfectly well"*

Comment: @Phil I mentioned up above I left out the connection query (which I'm completely sure is correct) just due to privacy information :)

Comment: @Kaleon You can still indicate whether or not you've brought `$con` into the appropriate scope. Please read [*Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example*](http://www.sscce.org/) for hints on how to ask a code related question

Comment: @Fred-ii- They are separate function and they execute one after the other (delete first) so when I only delete it will say

"Order: #deleteno succesfully deleted" - which is what I want it to do 

However when I update it will day 

"Query failed please enter a valid ID" followed by 

"Order: $updateno succesfully updated" 

So my issue isn't with either of these not completing their intended function it's just that when I update the deleteno error message appears!

Comment: Ok, we need to know how you're using both functions, because this doesn't make any sense. Try adding an exit somewhere in your update function, or a redirect.

Comment: `$con` , `$sql_db` not visible there

Comment: Are you posting both updateID and deleteID when you click either button from your HTML?  You probably should not do that.

Comment: @James yes they both share one button, however the user selects the criteria of what they want to do (update/delete) is there a way to make a button execute specific php commands?

Comment: As long as you're definitely calling either update or delete but not both it's ok.  It sounded like they were both being called and I wondered if you were checking just the updateID/deleteID being set in order to know what to do on the php side.  Since you've picked an answer I assume you've got it working and that this is not the case.

Comment: @Kaleon Syntax error in delete statement.please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(!isset($deleteno)) {
        $sql = "delete from orders where orderID = $deleteno;";
```

Are you sure you want to execute that block if $deleteno is NOT set?

P.S. You shouldn't rely on `$_POST['deleteId']` being a number. Please read about SQL injections, how to avoid them and also about using prepared statements.

Comment: I've tried changing it from !isset and isset but for some reason it will still execute the:

else {
                echo "<p>Order $deleteno succesfully deleted</p>"

statement in delete! 

Also in regards to SQL Injection, this we are learning about security next week (in my degree) so they told us not to worry about that for this small project, however I'm really excited to learn about it!

Comment: @Kaleon use `!empty()` and define `$con` `$sql_db` variables inside function.

Answer (score 0):

I've update your code, but you need to write cleaner code ( spaces, indents, etc ) this won't only help you to learn but to find your errors easily.

```
<?php

function DeleteButton()
{
    @mysqli_select_db($con , $sql_db);

    /*
            Checks if connection is successful 
    */
    if(!$con){
            echo"<p>Database connection failure</p>";
    } else {

            /*
                    Check if $_POST["deleteID"] exists, is not empty and it is numeric.
            */

            if(isset($_POST["deleteID"]) && ! empty($_POST["deleteID"]) && ctype_digit(empty($_POST["deleteID"]))

                    $deleteno = $_POST["deleteID"];
                    $sql = "delete from orders where orderID='$deleteno'";
                    $result = @mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                    if(!$result){
                            echo "<p>Query failed please enter a valid ID </p>"
                    } else {
                            echo "<p>Order $deleteno succesfully deleted</p>";
                            unset($deleteno);
                    }
            } else {
                 echo "<p>Please enter a valid ID </p>" ;
            }
    }
}


    /*
            Part 2:
            ===========================================================================
            Check if $_POST["updateID"] exists, is not empty and it is numeric.
            Check if $_POST["updatestatus"] exists, is not empty and equal to Paid or Fullfilled
    */


if( isset($_POST["updateID"]) && 
    ! empty($_POST["updateID"]) &&
    ctype_digit(empty($_POST["updateID"]) &&
    isset($_POST["updatestatus"]) &&
    ! empty($_POST["updatestatus"]) &&
    ( $_POST["updatestatus"] == "Fulfilled" || $_POST["updatestatus"] == "Paid" ) )      
{

$updateno = $_POST["updateID"];
$updatestatus = $_POST["updatestatus"];

    $sql ="update orders set orderstatus='$updatestatus' where orderID=$updateno;";
    $result = @mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if(!$result){
        echo "<p>Query failed please enter a valid ID</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Order: $updateno succesfully updated!</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in MySQL Syntax

```
$sql = "delete from orders where orderID = $deleteno;";
```

`$deleteno` after `orderID` must be inside single quotes.

change it to this `$sql = "delete from orders where orderID = '$deleteno';";`

Comment: Hey Nidhin for some reason it works perfectly without the single quotes, possibly because it's passing an INT not a string? I'm not sure but it works from here!

Comment: @Kaleon Thanks..I didn't know about INT case.I will try it next time.